# How do I charge my iPhone 6 without it being on the whole time?

Tags: iphone, charge

I've tried shutting off my iPhone 6 AFTER plugging it in to charge, and it will turn back on.  How can I make sure it stays off while charging so that it charges more quickly?

Comment: It will show the lock screen, which should nod off again within a few seconds. It should not fully wake. Please edit your question to provide further details.

Comment: Agree with @Tetsujin. Perhaps you could provide a sequence of actions to re-produce the issue.

Answer (score 6):

1. Plug the phone in to power
2. Then turn it off

If your charger is overloaded, faulty or your cable has issues, there could be an interruption of charge and the device will start up then. There's no way to prevent this necessary feature - it's a fail safe to turn on the device after replacing the battery or other system events that could cause the power to be low.

Answer (score -1):

Just put it in airplane mode, it will achieve the same desired result.

Comment: This reduces the power load on the system, but it's not the same result. Not all the energy will charge the battery if you don't actually power off the device. If you only can charge for an hour, this will put measurably more energy into the cell. The benefit is less noticeable if you are already more than 50 % charges as the trickle portion of the charge curve needs time to complete and not higher current.